# RealmSwift installation on Xcode

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods, realm

I am trying to create a project which uses Realm and RealmSwift. I have used Cocoapods to install these dependencies. I have seen the other posts too on stackoverflow and tried their solutions. They don't work for me. In my project, I'm getting the error `"No such module as RealmSwift"` when I write the `import RealmSwift` statement. Here are the steps I took for installation:

1. I created an empty xcode project
2. I went into terminal and navigated to my project directory
3. I gave the `pod init` command to create a pod file
4. I went into the pod file(it already had the `use_frameworks!` statement
5. I wrote in `pod 'Realm'` and `pod 'RealmSwift'`. I gave the sources as:

   source 'https://github.com/artsy/Specs.git'

   source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'

[image]

6. I wrote in `pod install`
7. The pods were installed successfully. I went into the .xcworkspace file.
8. I had already installed the realm plugin so I created a new realm object file
9. The template file opens with the following file. I'm getting the error that there is no RealmSwift module.

[image]

What am I doing wrong? Or what am I not doing? Is a bridging header required? Has anybody else managed to resolve this error?

Any relevant suggestions or insights are most welcome.

Comment: Just had a similar issue.
Step 10 should have been "Compile the project". Since it looks like if you are using a specific Pod for the first time XCode doesn't know about it until you compile the whole workspace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its working now! Its so weird since I didn't do anything. I just went into my pod file commented out the use_frameworks! statement and ran `pod update` on the terminal. It gave me an error, so I added it back to my pod file. I wrote in `pod update` again and hit enter. I restarted Xcode cleaned it and built it and I wasn't getting this error anymore.

Comment: This worked for me after a subsequent `pod install`. Thanks for the help. It would be great if someone could provide some insight into why this works and what is going on here.

Answer (score 0):

Need to uncomment platform in your pod file then try once again your pod.

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
  platform :ios, '9.0'   // Uncomment this 

# Uncomment this line if you're using Swift
 use_frameworks!

target 'Demo_Realm' do
pod 'RealmSwift'
end

target 'Demo_RealmTests' do

end

target 'Demo_RealmUITests' do

end
```

Comment: no you don't to need to do that unless you want to define a standard platform version for your product. It worked for me without doing any of that.

Comment: This tells CocoaPods that your project is targeting iOS 9.0 and will be using frameworks instead of static libraries.

Comment: no the `use_frameworks!` statement tells cocoapods that you are using dynamic frameworks. if you dont specify the platform, it just defines your pods on a global platform.